# Iterating through json object with python help needed

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am trying to search for a value inside a JSON object in python and cant seen to get it to do what I want

the JSON data looks like this

```
{"2103": 
  {"birth_state":null,
  "birth_city":null,
  "first_name":"Cody",
  "position":"OT",
  "depth_chart_order":null,
  "hashtag":"#CodyBooth-NFL-FA-60",
  "birth_country":null,
  "rotoworld_id":null,
  "search_last_name":"booth",
  "injury_body_part":null,
  "player_id":"2103",
  "number":60,
  "yahoo_id":27841,
  "age":27,
  "full_name":"Cody Booth",
  "injury_start_date":null,
  "team":null,
  "height":"6'5\"",
  "college":"Temple",
  "birth_date":"1991-04-22",
  "high_school":null,
  "sport":"nfl",
  "injury_notes":null,
  "fantasy_positions":["OL"],
  "rotowire_id":9866,
  "sportradar_id":"4cd4976e-e230-4935-ad3f-c12876a41350",
  "search_first_name":"cody",
  "injury_status":null,
  "search_rank":9999999,
  "stats_id":null,
  "search_full_name":"codybooth",
  "depth_chart_position":null,
  "practice_description":null,
  "news_updated":null,
  "practice_participation":null,
  "fantasy_data_id":16426,
  "espn_id":17054,
  "active":false,
  "years_exp":1,
  "last_name":"Booth",
  "weight":"285",
  "status":"Inactive",
  "gsis_id":null
},
"6250": 
  {"birth_state":null,
  "birth_city":null,
  "first_name":"Eurndraus",
  "position":"DT",
  "depth_chart_order":null,
  "hashtag":"#EurndrausBryant-NFL-LAC-0",
  "birth_country":null,
  "rotoworld_id":null,
  "search_last_name":"bryant",
  "injury_body_part":null,
  "player_id":"6250",
  "number":0,
  "yahoo_id":32538,
  "age":null,
  "full_name":"Eurndraus Bryant",
  "injury_start_date":null,
  "team":"LAC",
  "height":"",
  "college":null,
  "birth_date":null,
  "high_school":null,
  "sport":"nfl",
  "injury_notes":null,
  "fantasy_positions":["DL"],
  "rotowire_id":null,
  "sportradar_id":"9ff46edb-988f-4c8a-ad56-0502808ca1a6",
  "search_first_name":"eurndraus",
  "injury_status":null,
  "search_rank":9999999,
  "stats_id":null,
  "search_full_name":"eurndrausbryant",
  "depth_chart_position":null,
  "practice_description":null,
  "news_updated":null,
  "practice_participation":null,
  "fantasy_data_id":21183,
  "espn_id":3916426,
  "active":true,
  "years_exp":0,
  "last_name":"Bryant",
  "weight":"",
  "status":"Active",
  "gsis_id":null
},
....}
```

I am trying to feed in a field that will match on "search_full_name" so i need to search each object's "search_full_name" field for a match and then write the object key to a variable. but everything I try returns a type error or some other error.

Here is the code for irritating I am trying to use

```
def get_player_key(search_name, requestor):
players = Players().get_all_players()

found_players = []
for player in players:
    if player['search_full_name'] == search_name:
        found_players.append((player, player['full_name'], player['position'], player['team'], [requestor]))
```

Comment: **What** 'type error or some other error'? Be specific.

Comment: why did you add `iterator` tag? what's the expected result?

Comment: Where are you extracting the json data? You can use `json.loads()` to load that data into a dictionary and perform a quick `get` on the dictionary to pull the values you want. Otherwise you can display a message stating no information exists.

Comment: can you post your desired output?

Comment: You can use json.loads() it converts null to None

Comment: This looks like a rant or maybe an implicit request for code, not an actual question.

Comment: to answer some questions I have tried several different things and gotten several different errors but they all seem to revolve around 'player' not being a dict item. it seems like when i do ' for player in players' it is only grabbing the key (i.e. 2103) and not the object associated with that key

Comment: the data is already in a dictionary. if I try 'json.loads()' it tells me it expects a string not a dictionary

Comment: the error i am getting with the bit of code above is 'TypeError: string indices must be integers' on the line 'if player['search_full_name'] == search_name:'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to fix this by setting a new object based on the current key

```
def get_player_key(search_name, requestor):
    players = get_all_players()
    found_players = []


    for player_id in players:
         player = players[player_id]
         if player['search_full_name'] ==  search_name:
            #Blah Blah Blah
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are getting the error that *String indices can't be integer* while trying to use player['search_full_name']. In case you want to index into a dict, you can't use strings, rather you should use the get function.

Here is a functional code (Assume the json is in a file info.json)

```
import json
with open("info.json","r") as f:
    t=f.read()
players=json.loads(t);
found_players=[]
for player in players.values():
    if player.get('search_full_name')=='eurndrausbryant':
        found_players.append((player, player.get('full_name'), player.get('position'), player.get('team')))
```

You can easily stick it back into your function and use *player.get('search_full_name')==search_name* rather than the hardcoding I have done here :)

Comment: I was getting String indices can't be integer, but when I try json.loads() i get an error saying it expects string not dict, so it is already a dictionary item.

Comment: Just skip the step of json.loads() and try it then. Should work :)